# How can i generate a patch file from all commits in a local branch (GIT)?

Tags: git, patch

I would like to generate a patch with all commits from a local branch. Without Comparing to the master. (because a part of the commits are already merged with the master.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git diff srchash..HEAD > whatever.patch` with `srchash` being the SHA-1 of the base commit. If the branch is not currently checked out, use `branchname` instead of `HEAD`